# How to create AutoHotKey which starts script (i.e .bat) using Cmder command line arguments?

Tags: windows, autohotkey, cmder

I am trying to create an autohotkey which starts a script (i.e .bat):

```
#!g::
  Run "Path\To\script\script.bat" debug
  Return
```

The AutoHotKey works properly. However, I would like the .bat to be opened using Cmder instead of the default windows cmd.

I tried to set the Cmder as the default cmd by going to **Settings-> Integration -> Default term** and by checking the ***"Force ConEmu as default terminal for console applications"***, but this did not change anything in my particular case, and the script is still being ran in windows cmd.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming Cmder can take a command line parameter, make it explicit:

`Run "Path\To\exe\Cmder.exe Path\To\script\script.bat" debug`

Else, run Cmder and then use AHK to file open the script.

**EDIT**: Based on OP's solution, could try:

`Run "Path\To\exe\Cmder.exe /Task ""Path\To\script\script.bat debug"""`

or

`Run "Path\To\exe\Cmder.exe /Start ""Path\To\script"" /Task ""script.bat debug"""`

The exact syntax and whether and where to surround things with quotes is tbd, but try and see.

Comment: I have just tried that and it does not work. It seems that Cmder can take a command line parameter, but the command line parameter is interpreted as a folder path to which Cmder will change directory to. Anyway, thanks for the suggestion

Comment: I guess cmder doesn't support any parameters (other than /Start, /Single, etc) so you would have to kludge it with a bat file 
 https://github.com/cmderdev/cmder/issues/370 or having AHK pass the file name to run into the open cmder window.

Comment: I managed to do it by making the AHK type the script.bat and press enter after opening the Cmder

Comment: @dj_frunza I am trying to do a similar thing, did you use Sent or ControlSend? I can't seem to get ControlSend to work with cmder

Comment: I used "send". Please check my answer to see how it worked for me !

Answer (score 1):

In the end I used below script to make it work:

```
; Win+Alt+y - Start script
#!y::
Run "d:\cmder\Cmder.exe" "d:\somePath\FolderContainingTheBat\"
sleep 1000
send script.bat debug{enter}

Return
```

**EDIT**

Another solution for this does not involve AutoHotKey and works only with default windows cmd. I did the following:

1. Create a .bat file which contains the following

   ```
   script.bat debug
   ```
2. Create shortcut for the newly created bat file and assign to it a "keyboard shortcut": Right click on the created shortcut -> Properties -> "Shortcut" tab -> Shortcut key

Comment: Excellent. Glad it is working.  Why so much sleep, though? Maybe try a WinWait or WinWaitActive?  Anyway, please see my original answer for the ***Edit*** because there may be some command line arguments that are supported, and it may be a question of surrounding the parameters with quotes (which need "" in ahk).

Comment: I tried with WinWait and WinWait Active and it did not work. Also I tried it with Start and Task but withouth any luck whatsoever

Comment: Thx for letting me know. Glad you found a good solution though.

Answer (score 0):

I made it work with this

```
Run, C:\path\Cmder\vendor\conemu-maximus5\ConEmu64.exe C:\path\to\script.exe
```